# Marshal.ReleaseComObject() while in SQL Transaction

Tags: c#, transactions, com, sapb1

We're using SAP Business One which is backed by a SQL Database. All scripted writes/updates to the database have to go through managed COM in .Net/C#.

COM in itself seems like a can of worms: everybody seems to have an opinion on whether the objects need to be explicitly released and if so how, or you can just leave it up to the Garbage Collector (or force using GC.Collect()).

We're in the situation where we want to make updates/inserts to multiple documents (SQL Tables) at once, so we're using Transactions to do this, which works basically the same as they do in SQL.

The question is: Should we dispose/release the COM objects while in a Database transaction or should we defer this and risk losing the references to the COM objects/getting a memory leak?
What is the performance penalty/time cose of releasing COM objects in this way?

**TL;DR**: Should COM objects be released while within a Database Transaction, or should it be deferred/ignored altogether?

```
// pseudocode - greatly simplified

// case 1 - current setup
Transaction.Start();
comObject.subObject = new comSubOject();
comObject.Add();
Marshall.ReleaseComObject(comObject);
Marshall.ReleaseComObject(subObject);
Transaction.Commit();

// case 2 - ideal case, much harder to structure code this way
Transaction.Start();
comObject.subObject = new comSubOject();
comObject.Add();
Transaction.Commit();
Marshall.ReleaseComObject(comObject);
Marshall.ReleaseComObject(subObject);
```

Comment: Why `GC.Collect` in the title?

Comment: Just updated the question - some people say you can just force COM cleanup using `GC.Collect()`, but I'm sure it's not great practice to do that